# How to conditionally render component using a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where I want to display some elements on condition:

```
export interface MyComponentProps{
   chidren: ReactNode
}
export const MyComponent= (props: MyComponentProps) => {
   const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);

   useEffect(() => {
      // ... some initialization stuff
      
      console.log("DEBUG APP INITIALIZED");
      setIsInitialized(true);
   }, [setIsInitialized]):
   return <>{isInitialized && props.children }</>
}
```

In calling component :

```
     export const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
            
            const renderContent = () => {
                console.log("Render The Content");
                return (
                   <Provider>
                      // .... load provider, divs, etc.
                   </Provider>
                );
            } 
       
            return <div>
                        {
                          isAppEmbeded ? 
                              <MyComponent>
                                   <h1>Embeded Mode</h1>
                                   <div>{renderContent()}</div>
                               </MyComponent>
                         :
                            renderContent()
                        }
                   </div>
       
        }
```

The problem is that renderContent is called before my initialization stuff finished. So in console I have:

```
Render the Content
DEBUG APP INITIALIZED
```

**Question is, how to conditionally render the renderContent function component ?**

Thank you!

Comment: Your dependencies array should be `[isInitialized]`, not `[setIsInitialized]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to add a `render` function to `MyComponenet` that is only called once `initialized` is true.

```
export const MyComponent= (props: MyComponentProps) => {
   const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);

   useEffect(() => {
      // ... some initialization stuff
      
      console.log("DEBUG APP INITIALIZED");
      setIsInitialized(true);
   }, []):
   
   if (isInitialized) {
       return props.render();
   }
   return null; // or something else
}
```

Then your use of `MyComponent` changes:

```
<MyComponent render={() => <>
    <h1>Embeded Mode</h1>
    <div>{renderContent()}</div>
</>}
```

And a side note - you don't need `setIsInitialized` in your dependencies for `useEffect`